# How to save multiple ManytoMany instances to a Django object?

Tags: django, manytomanyfield

I have a django app with several Question objects.  Question and Quiz are related through a ManyToManyField.  I want to create Quiz objects such that each quiz is randomly assigned 3 questions.

I've tried to create a save method in my model where I: use a queryset to get 3 questions, save the Quiz instance (to save an id), set the queryset to the Quiz and save again. Most of my searches on this topic have shown where people are using a form to save the m2m object.

Even better, is it possible to set 3 questions to a quiz object using a view? Ultimately this is where I want to get to.  A user will select a **LearnGoal** using **request.GET** in a view, and this LearnGoal will restrict the questions that will be added to the Quiz.

My models.py so far:

```
class LearnGoal(models.Model):
    goal_name = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    goal_description = models.TextField()

class Question(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    learngoal = models.ForeignKey(LearnGoal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    q_text = models.TextField()
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=12)

class Quiz(models.Model):
    """quiz which will have three questions."""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(Question)
    completed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    my_answer = models.CharField(max_length=12)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """need to create an instance first, for the m2m"""
        super(Quiz, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        """get 3 random questions"""
        three_questions = Quiz.objects.all().order_by('?')[0:3]
        self.questions.set(three_questions)
        super(Quiz, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I've tried a few variations of the above code.  Currently this code gives the error:
`'Question' instance expected, got <Quiz: Quiz object (4)>` from the line `self.questions.set(five_questions)`

How can I save multiple questions to one instance of the quiz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Quiz.save` method, you can do:

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    ...
    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.add_questions = False

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # We need this to prevent updating questions
        # on updating the Quiz instance
        if self.pk is None:
            self.add_questions = True
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.add_questions:
            # No need to run save again; M2M relationships are set
            # through an intermediate model
            self.questions.set(Question.objects.order_by('?')[:3])
```

Note that, random ordering (`order_by('?')`) is slow but whether that will affect you totally depends on the use case.

Comment: That works. The "Questions" in the last line should be Question.  I can mark your solution accept, although I did edit my question around the same time you gave your answer, let me know what is appropriate.  I also need to look more into `(order_by('?'))`. Speed should be ok I think with always less than 50 objects but it's not very random.

Comment: @DougSmith Doing this at the model level is fine unless you have some specific business logic for this in the view layer because you're basically creating relations between instances of two models.

Comment: What I'm thinking is that I first need user input for a particular LearnGoal. The user would pick the LearnGoal and now `self.questions.set(Question.objects.filter(learngoal.id=x).order_by('?')[:3])`.  Maybe I should think on that for a while and make it a new question.