# How to add to ManyToMany when getting "no attribute" error?

Tags: django, manytomanyfield

Using a form, I'm trying to add items to the manytomany field `questions` of a `Quiz` object after first getting a queryset of the questions I want to add. I save the ModelForm but when I add the item, I get an AttributError: `'function' object has no attribute 'questions'`

Previously I was able to [create a Quiz object with 3 random questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58787050/how-to-save-multiple-manytomany-instances-to-a-django-object) using a save method in the model.  However, I don't see a way to add 3 questions from a particular queryset using only the model

views.py

```
def choose(request, obj_id):
    """Get the id of the LearnObject of interest"""
    """Filter the questions and pick 3 random Qs"""
    my_qs = Question.objects.filter(learnobject_id=obj_id)
    my_qs = my_qs.order_by('?')[0:3]
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QuizForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_quiz = form.save
            for item in my_qs:
                new_quiz.questions.add(item)
            new_quiz.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/quizlet/quiz-list')
    else:
        form = QuizForm()  
    return render(request, 'quizlet/quiz_form.html', {'form': form})
```

and models.py

```
class LearnObject(models.Model):
    """model for the learning objective"""
    code = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    desc = models.TextField()

class Question(models.Model):
    """model for the questions."""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    learnobject = models.ForeignKey(
        LearnObject, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        )
    q_text = models.TextField()
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=12)

class Quiz(models.Model):
    """quiz which will have three questions."""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(Question)
    completed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    my_answer = models.CharField(max_length=12)

class QuizForm(ModelForm):
    """test out form for many2many"""
    class Meta:
        model = Quiz
        fields = ['name', 'my_answer']
```

The error happens at the line `new_quiz.questions.add(item)`. I don't understand this since the model of `Quiz` has a field `questions`, and the object (I think) has a already been created on the first `new_quiz = form.save()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the next line: `new_quiz = form.save`, you are missing the `()`, change it to `new_quiz = form.save()`.

If not you are saving the reference of the function `form.save` to the `new_quiz`, instead of the object returned by the function.